# How to allow special characters like '," in catalog search?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.2, magento2.3, magento2.2.4

How to allow special characters like '," in catalog search ? If I search with abc'th it results all products.

Comment: can you post the code you tried?

Comment: no idea till now

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: till now no solution